# Can you upload chef cookbooks directly from a hosted Git repository?

Tags: git, knife, chef

I'm learning Chef. My cookbooks are on Github. It seems the workflow goes:

1. Install cookbooks locally (download them from Github with `knife site install`)
2. Upload cookbooks to server (`knife cookbook upload`)
3. Deploy to client from server (`knife ssh ... "sudo chef-client"`)

Is there a way to combine 1 and 2? It's not critical, but sometimes I need to conserve bandwidth. And I'd like to know if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opscode made an opinionated choice to keep Chef & Git separate, and have spoken about it on multiple occasions - maybe someone else isn't using Git, maybe it shouldn't be as tied into source control as it is, etc.

Consider this: `knife cookbook site install apache2` by default is *not* going to Github, rather the Community Site where cookbooks are released (similar to rubygems).

Keeping them separate also allows the flexibility of multiple people working on a cookbook, checking in their code, and finally, when you are ready, deploy it to the chef server as a unit of code to be deployed.

So in short, there's no built-in method to combine items 1&2.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure I follow the reasoning (allowing a shortcut between A and B doesn't couple A to B), but you answered my question.

Comment: Well, yes - it seems poor form to accept the first answer so quickly though.